# issue with a regex in a sed script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm facing an interesting issue with a regexp, i'm using this within a small sed script (bash), 
here it is:

```
cities="new york;milan;rome;paris;london"
 echo ${cities} | sed 's/new.*;//'
```

This prints: London 
Basically the script substitutes everything until the last semicolon occurrence, while what i want is to simply delete whats matched by (new.*) until the first occurrence of the semicolon 
Any advice?

Comment: As such, your question is ill-formed; sed *is* replacing the text which matches `new.*;`

Comment: Please update your question to show the expected output if you replace new york and if you replace london as it affects the solution significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a non-greedy substitution:

```
sed 's/new[^;]*;//'
```

This doesn't work if your data strings do not end with a semi-colon. In that case you could do something like this:

```
sed 's/new[^;]*//g; s/;;/;/g; s/^;|;$//g'
```

#### Edit

As noted by Ed in the comments, the second solution does not preserve empty fields. If that is needed this works (as far as I've tested it):

```
sed 's/;?new[^;]*$|new[^;]*;//g'
```

Comment: That second sed would remove blank fields that existed in the input prior to your substitution which Id think would be undesirable. Are you just trying to handle the case where "new york" could appear at the end of the line? If so then just `sed 's/new[^;]*(;|$)//'` would do it. If that's not an RE your sed can handle then just use `awk '{sub(new[^;]*(;|$)/,"")}1'`.

Comment: I guess `s/;;/;/g` instead of `s/;;//g` ?

Comment: You can also `s/new[^;]*\(;\|$\)/` to do it in a single expression.

Comment: @EdMorton and @JoSo: the trouble with the `(;|$)` bit is that it leaves a `;` at the end. I guess `s/;new[^;]*$|new[^;]*;//g` is a more appropriate alternative, but I don't like having to repeat the pattern ...

Comment: @Thor - leaves a semi-colon at the end of what? I'm not sure what the case is you're trying to handle. Could you edit your response to post the input and output?

Comment: @EdMorton: sorry for not being clear. If the pattern is at the end of the input: `london;new york` the result is `london;`, while if it were reversed (`new york;london`) the result is `london`.

Comment: @Thor Ah, now I understand, thanks. So the issue is - what does the OP want? For just the matching text between ;s to be removed or for the matching text plus a ; on either side of it to be removed? Without the answer to that, we're just guessing.

Comment: @Thor: I don't think it leaves a `;` at the end.

Comment: @JoSo: compare `echo 'new york;london' | sed 's/new[^;]*\(;\|$\)//'` to `echo 'london;new york' | sed 's/new[^;]*\(;\|$\)//'`; it's not consistent. It might be ok for the OP though.